# how does BackboneJS view's function binding works?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I am reading through [BackboneJS View](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/) .

```
   SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            alert("Alerts suck.");
        }
    });

    // The initialize function is always called when instantiating a Backbone View.
    // Consider it the constructor of the class.
    var search_view = new SearchView();
```

Is every function inside a View object called on instantiation or is it only the initialize function alone??

Is initialize more like a callback function on success of instantiating a view? what exactly is it meant for?

I went through google. But found most results having buzz words that i couldn't understand. can someone put it straight away simple? assuming I have no knowledge about underscorejs?

Comment: try reading this http://tech.pro/tutorial/1476/part-2-backbonejs-deconstructed and see if this helps

Comment: It's the initialization function where you put view-specific code. No, every method isn't run, why would they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `initialize` function is called on instantiation. You can regard it as a constructor of sorts.

Even in the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor), the title of the initialize function is `constructor/initialize`.

> ... If the view defines an initialize function, it will be called when the view is first created.

It would make no sense at all if every function was called on instantiation. Imagine a case where you have some destructive logic in one of the functions of your class (which is very likely), you wouldn't want that function called right away.

Any other functions that you want to execute the moment the object is instantiated can simply be called from within the initialize function.

```
initialize: function(){
    // alert("Alerts are not too cool (no offence).");
    console.log( "Consoles are cool" );
    another_init_func();
    more_init_stuff();
    be_awesome();
    ...
}
```